# Showing data from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here's the code I'm currently using, but it's not working:

```
<?php
$jsonData = file_get_contents('http://example.com/bin/serp.php?engine=google&phrase=stackoverflow');

$a = json_decode($jsonData,true);
 foreach($a[0] as $item):
      echo '<span>'.$item['title'].'</span>';
      echo '<span>'.$item['url'].'</span>';
      echo '<span>'.$item['description'].';</span>';
 endforeach;
?>
```

However, all the above code is doing is showing `;SSS;AAA;hhh;` on my page.

Here's a copy of the JSON data that's being retrieved with `file_get_contents`:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [idx] => 0 [title] => Stack Overflow [description] => A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers. [url] => http://stackoverflow.com/ ) [1] => Array ( [idx] => 1 [title] => Stack Overflow - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia [description] => Stack Overflow website logo.png · Stack Overflow.png. Screenshot of Stack Overflow as of December 2011. Web address · stackoverflow.com. Commercial? Yes. [url] => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow ) [2] => Array ( [idx] => 2 [title] => Why I no longer contribute to StackOverflow â€” Michael T. Richter [description] => I was active in the StackOverflow (and the broader Stack Exchange) community for a while. I no longer am. Here's why. [url] => http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow ) [3] => Array ( [idx] => 3 [title] => Newest 'stackoverflow' Questions - Meta Stack Exchange [description] => Download data for StackOverflow User Survey? The DropBox link to download the data for this survey is expired. Is there another place to get the data? [url] => http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow ) [4] => Array ( [idx] => 4 [title] => Browse Queries - Stack Exchange Data Explorer [description] => StackOverflow Rank and Percentile. nov 4 12 Cade Roux. 56. 29k views ... Most popular StackOverflow tags in May 2010. aug 27 11 lukasz.lew. 10. 29k views ... [url] => http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries ) [5] => Array ( [idx] => 5 [title] => Return to StackOverflow.org [description] => StackOverflow.org began as the merging of two ideas that have been kicking around in my head for years. First, I wanted a dorky programming-related domain  ... [url] => http://stackoverflow.org/ ) [6] => Array ( [idx] => 6 [title] => StackOverflow Update: 560M Pageviews a Month, 25 Servers, and ... [description] => The network of sites that make up StackExchange, which includes StackOverflow, is now ranked 54th for traffic in the world; they have 110 sites ... [url] => http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html ) ) )
```

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you getting a json data or object from 'file_get_contents'? If u getting json data no need for the json_decode line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `json_decode()` already returns an array so no need to wrap in in another array:

```
$a = array(json_decode($jsonData,true));
```

should be:

```
$a = json_decode($jsonData,true);
```

Also, if the var_dump is from `$jsonData` and not `$a` then that array is two levels deep and you'll need to go one level deeper to reach your values:

```
foreach($a[0] as $item):
```

Comment: I just updated my code on the site and in the question above based on the suggestions you made.  But now it's showing `;SSS;AAA;hhh;` for some reason.  Did I not make one of the changes correctly?

Comment: It looks to me like it's showing the first letter of each item 3 times in a row.  `S` for StackOverflow, `A` for A, `h` for `http://stackoverflow.com/`.

Answer (score 0):

this will give you an object not an array

try  `echo '<span>'.$item->title.'</span>';`

or remove array from this line

```
$a = array(json_decode($jsonData,true));
```

Comment: By passing `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode()` you get an array back instead of an object.